# Rewriting setInterval function using Underscore debounce

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I'm rewriting my setInterval task so that I no longer have to clearInterval when I jump to a different tab on my site using Underscore.js debounce.

I keep getting the error `_.debounce is not a function`.

This is my original working code below. Basically, when the tab is 'pano', I run this function that changes the camera angle every 50ms. When I reclick on the 'pano' tab, clearInterval resets the timer.

```
clearInterval(timerID);
if (target == 'pano') {
   initialize();
   timerID = setInterval(function(){
     if (!hovering && !moved) {
       panoOptions.pov.heading += .5;      
       panoOptions.pov.heading = wrapAngle(panoOptions.pov.heading);
       panorama.setOptions(panoOptions);
     }
   },50);

  initialize();

}
```

When I try to refactor my code to use `._debounce` (http://underscorejs.org/#debounce), I get an error and am not if my approach is correct.

```
timerID = _.debounce(function(){
  if (!hovering && !moved) {
    panoOptions.pov.heading += .5;      
    panoOptions.pov.heading = wrapAngle(panoOptions.pov.heading);
    panorama.setOptions(panoOptions);
  }
},50);

$("#pano_toggle").click(
  function(){
    console.log("CLICKED");
    timerID();
  }
);
```

I basically set up a click listener so that when the user clicks on the button, the debounce function starts running. I also added `console.log("CLICKED")` to see if my click listener is working, but it isn't picking up the click.

Any tip on where my logic is failing?

Edit:

I made sure to require Underscore.js:

```
require(["require", 
         "jquery", 
         "underscore",
         "lib/jquery/jquery.galleria",
         "gmaps!",
         "//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js",
         "twitter_bootstrap/bootstrap-dropdown"], function(require, _){
```

Comment: Your error is `_.debounce is not a function`? You did put a `<script src="path/to/underscore.js"></script>` in your markup right?

Comment: @alpha123 Yes, I made sure to include the script. I'll play around with the naming/path to see if that is the issue.

Comment: @alpha - unless he defined "_" elsewhere, I believe you'd get a different error than "debounce is not a function", but I could be wrong about that. It would be nice though to have a link to your site where this is failing or a fiddle, I haven't been able to replicate the error.

Comment: @bubbles Let me add the part where I require underscore.js

Comment: @hyngyn Ah ha! You're using AMD. Unless you edited it, underscore doesn't register itself as an AMD module anymore.

Comment: `timerID` is a misleading variable name - it's a function, not an id.

Comment: @Bergi, Agreed, I changed it on my local machine :) THanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your require syntax is not correct.  Modules get passed to your function as arguments in the order that they were listed in the first array.  So it should look something like this:

```
require([
     "require", 
     "jquery", 
     "underscore",
     "lib/jquery/jquery.galleria",
     "gmaps!",
     "//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js",
     "twitter_bootstrap/bootstrap-dropdown"
], function(require, $, _, galleria, ...){
     /* .... */
});
```

Although, you shouldnt need to require **require** itself.